# GSS-API Java strange error

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, gssapi

I'm running the following tutorial:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/BasicClientServer.html

I'm getting the following prompts:

```
Connected to server localhost/127.0.0.1
Kerberos username [login]: {I enter my username here}
Kerberos password for login: {I enter my password here}
```

I get the following error:

Can you ascertain the root cause of this?

```
Exception in thread "main" GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getTgt(Krb5InitCredential.java:333)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:128)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:106)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:172)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:209)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:195)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:162)
at demo.SampleClient.main(SampleClient.java:145)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:696)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:542)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokeCreatorPriv(LoginContext.java:703)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:575)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSUtil.login(GSSUtil.java:246)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getTicket(Krb5Util.java:136)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:328)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getTgt(Krb5InitCredential.java:325)
... 7 more
Caused by: KrbException: Message stream modified (41)
at sun.security.krb5.KrbKdcRep.check(KrbKdcRep.java:53)
at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:96)
at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReq.getReply(KrbAsReq.java:449)
at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.sendASRequest(Credentials.java:410)
at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireTGT(Credentials.java:378)
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:662)
... 23 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering if this is a possibility (ie even if registry key is set, locked out for local administrators):

http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~weijun/special/krb5winguide-2/raw_files/new/kwin

Known Issues

If an AD account is also added into local administrator group on the
   client PC, Microsoft restricts such client from getting the session key
   for tickets (even if you set the allowtgtsessionkey registry key to 1).
   The workaround is: Just forget you're a logged in user, call kinit.exe.
   Do not depends on LSA credential cache.

Answer (score 4):

I got exceptions “Message stream modified (41)”, when the Kerberos realm didn’t match. The realm (in system property `java.security.krb5.realm`) has to match exactly, including upper/lower case.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm that issue. I do have admin rights on my machine and still are able to obtain the session key from the LSA. You should enable full debug ouput on JGSS and the Krb5LoginModule. Share your krb5.ini and login.conf too. I hope your are aware that the above example cannot work because your client cannot obtain a ticket for a local host. It has to be a FQDN with an appropriate SPN set in the Active Directory.

Comment: Because of your prompt and the target server. Re-read my answer for the reason.

Comment: The tutorial sets the expectation that a username prompt will occur:

>For this tutorial, the Kerberos login module com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule is specified in the configuration file. This login module prompts for a Kerberos name and password and attempts to authenticate to the Kerberos KDC.

I'm happy that my target server is incorrect, but you seem to be suggesting I shouldn't be expecting a prompt.

Comment: This is fine but it's easier to work with the credentials cache. That's what I was referring to. LSA in Windows. Post all of your config. This will help.